# Call a JavaScript function from one JSP inside another JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have this JavaScript (below) in A.jsp and I would like to call the function `deleteLANode(nodeUniqueId);` which is in B.jsp. I can't use include `jsp:include page="B.jsp"` because that loads other functions that are only designed for B.jsp.

Is it possible to call a JS function from one JSP in another JSP? If not what's the best way to work around this with out creating the same function in both JSP's.

```js
function executeConfirmDel(nodeUniqueId) {
  $("#dialog-hello").dialog({
    buttons: [{
      text: "Confirm",
      "class": "btn btn-primary button-width-medium",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        deleteLANode(nodeUniqueId);
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      "class": "btn btn-default",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
```

Comment: You cannot achieve this in the manner you require. A better solution would be to extract common logic to it's own file (or preferably scope/namespace) and then include that in your page.

Comment: put the function in a javascript file, include the javascript file in both pages

Comment: just create a script `.js` file with all the javascript that should be reused., and include that file via `<script src="your_javascript_file.js">`

Comment: My problem with this is that deleteLANode is a function that calls many different functions and those functions call other functions and so on in A.jsp

Comment: All of the function's dependencies should also be in the js file.

Comment: javascript:window.opener.deleteLANode(nodeUniqueId);      This is how I fixed it